# Is it Ok to remove the Hyper-V role from Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: hyper-v

I'm currently [tearing my hair out](https://serverfault.com/questions/274802/cannot-connect-to-a-hyper-v-virtual-machine) over an inability to connect to a Hyper-V VM on a Windows 2008 R2 Server.

One of the straws I'm considering clutching at is a complete removal of the Hyper-V role, and then adding it back in again.

Is there anything I should consider before trying that?  I don't have physical access to the box, so I'm somewhat nervous of doing anything that could mess up the host OS.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how the networks are set up (you hopefully dont share hyper-v and management interfaces on one physical nic) you may loose network configuration... becasue the network configuration is on the virtual network card that your host uses, then after removal it uses the configuratin on the physical card.. which may be wrong.

That said - how can you not have physical access to the box? Who puts a box into a data center these days without spending the 70 or so euro for an IPMI / KVM controller card? Last time I had to reinstall a server I even remotely configured the bios level RAID controller using the nice little IPMI daughter card.

Comment: I'm also surprised he didn't test out the IPSec policy changes locally before shipping it to a colo (and why he's not doing the IPSec tunnel on a separate physical hardware is a mystery as well).

Comment: Well, I appreciate your ongoing help guys, and I'm the first to admit to my obvious n00b status when it comes to all this stuff.  It's not that much of a mystery why we're obviously not getting everything right - we're a very small company, on an extremely tight budget, and we have to do everything ourselves, with a painful lack of knowledge and experience.  Er, that's why I'm asking questions here.

Comment: Sure. But realize that "extremely tight budget" does not go with "hhave complex stuff be worked by people not konwing what they do". At what point is it more effective to hire someone who KNOWS WHAT HE DOES than to spend a week figuring out the basics? A pro would not have ordered a computer without lights out capabilities, which are CHEAP these days. And believe me, you WILL pay for that ;) I did, a lot of times.

Comment: There's nothing much I can say really - sure, if I had the money, and knew someone I could rely on to do this stuff, I'd hire him or her.  However, that's not an option, so I need to spend the time figuring out the basics.  I'm not claiming to be skilled where I'm not, just doing the best I can with the resources I have.  I'd obviously do a bit better if you could tell me what's wrong with my IPSEC filter on the other question, instead of haranguing me for my ineptitude.

Comment: O, top - thriw away ipsec. Use RRAS firewall to only allow the ports through that you need. Alternatively establish aa back end network and get a separate router to handle your traffic including loggin into a vpn (pptp). A mikrotik 750 can handle that and cists around 60 USD. And get an ILO card. You need remote control.